# How to change color of edge on mouse hover in a ring network?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

How do I change the color of the edges when I hover my mouse over a node in a ring network?

For example, in this example: http://d3plus.org/examples/basic/9034389/

[image: Mouseover shows default color]

whenever we hover over `Alpha`, the default color is shown. Is it possible to change it to any other color like blue, green, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color on hover using [`.color()`](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#color-string--function--object-). For example, to change to blue, use:

```
var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .color({primary: "#0000ff"}) // <--- change color on hover to blue!
    .container("#viz")  // container DIV to hold the visualization
    .type("rings")      // visualization type
    .edges(connections) // list of node connections
    .focus("alpha")     // ID of the initial center node
    .draw()             // finally, draw the visualization!
```

Comment: You can color each edge individually by passing an `Object` to `edges()`, where the key `value` maps to `connections` and `color` maps to a function that chooses the color of each edge (e.g. `{value: connections, color: function(d){ if (d.source.id == 'alpha' && d.target.id == 'beta') return 'yellow'; else return 'blue'; }}`. I don't see how to change the colors on hover, though.